# Angular2 RC5 WebPack ngRx Hot Module Replacement

Tags: angular, webpack, ngrx, hot-module-replacement

I have previously used the approach found [here](http://teropa.info/blog/2016/08/08/angular-2-hot-loading-with-ngrx-store-and-webpack.html) to get HMR working with RC4 to maintain ngRX state when using Webpack.

With RC5 and ngModules the bootstrapping process has changed and I am struggling to see how I can adapt the previous approach to work with this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest an alternative way of doing this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tero has created a special repo for that ;)

[ngrx-hotload-rc5](https://github.com/teropa/ngrx-hotload-rc5)